# how to return the second node of a path in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query for finding paths:

```
MATCH p =(o:Order)-[r:seeks*2..8]->(o:Order)
WHERE o.Name="000089"
  AND ALL(x IN tail(nodes(p))
          WHERE SINGLE(y IN tail(nodes(p))
                       WHERE x=y))
RETURN extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.Name) AS OrderID, length(p) 
ORDER BY length(p)
```

My output is:

OrderID length(p)

1. [000089, **000091**, 000089]                                    2
2. [000089, **000093**, 000090, 000089]                            3
3. [000089, **000091**, 000096, 000095, 000090, 000089]            5
4. [000089, **000091**, 000096, 000097, 000093, 000090, 000089]    6
5. [000089, **000091**, 000098, 000092, 000095, 000090, 000089]    6
6. [000089, **000093**, 000090, 000096, 000097, 000091, 000089]    6
7. [000089, **000093**, 000094, 000092, 000097, 000091, 000089]    6

So, what I also want to is to return the second node on each path like (the nodes marked in bold above):

1. [000091]
2. [000093]
3. [000091]
4. [000091]
5. [000091]
6. [000093]
7. [000093]

Comment: What is the goal of the second part of your `WHERE` condition, `ALL(x IN tail(nodes(p) WHERE SINGLE(y IN tail(nodes(p)) WHERE x=y))`? As far as I can see, this is already ensured by the `MATCH` clause: `(o:Order)-[r:seeks*2..8]->(o:Order)` -> this makes sure that the start and the end of the path are the same.

Comment: The second part is not to visit a node in a path twice other than the starting and the ending node.

Comment: Neo4j makes sure that it does not use the same relationships twice: see the notes on [uniqueness](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#cypherdoc-uniqueness). This might work for your use case as well (depending on the details of your data model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple dataset for experimenting:

```
CREATE
   (o1:Order {Name: '0089'})-[:seeks]->
   (o2:Order {Name: '0090'})-[:seeks]->
   (o3:Order {Name: '0091'})-[:seeks]->(o1)
```

This an `(o1)->(o2)->(o3)->(o1)` circle.

Use the `nodes` function to extract the nodes on the path and index the list to second node. Lists in Cypher are indexed from zero.

```
MATCH p=(o:Order {Name: '0089'})-[r:seeks*2..8]->(o:Order)
RETURN nodes(p)[1]
```

Alternatively, you can do it without using a path variable and getting the `endNode` of the first relationship (note that this will only work for directed relationships):

```
MATCH (o:Order {Name: '0089'})-[r:seeks*2..8]->(o:Order)
RETURN endNode(r[0])
```